# How to open tel, mailto, whatsapp links in a flutter webview?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

I am a web developer and beginner to flutter.
I created a Flutter web view application by watching a few tutorials and its working fine for iOS and Android. But when I click on tel:'0123456789', mailto:'abc@gmail.com', WhatsApp link (https://wa.me/9712345678), it's going page Not Found. I want to open an external application for those conditions.
How to handle this task in a flutter to support in iOS and Android?
I used the flutter webview plugin to launch a url like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
              url: "https://www.website.com/",
              appBar: null,
              withJavascript: true,
              hidden: true,
              enableAppScheme: true,
            ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What about url_launcher plugin?

Comment: Didn't support too

Comment: did you got any answer for this?

Comment: no, not yet. I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: did you find any solution????

Comment: @engmms no, I didn't find any solution. I hide the div for mobile users.

Answer (score 2):

Install `flutter_url_launcher` from https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

return WebView(

  ...

  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {                
    
  if (request.url.contains('wa.me')) {
    launch(request.url); //This is where Whatsapp launches
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
  }

  ...
});
```

You can do the same thing for `tel:` and `mailto:` if you want user to use native apps for calling or sending email.

```
return WebView(

  ...

  navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {                
    
  if (request.url.contains('mailto:')) {
    launch(request.url);
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
  }

  if (request.url.contains('tel:')) {
    launch(request.url);
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
  }

  ...
});
```